# Calling base class method from overloaded method in sub-class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Perhaps I am just not using the correct terminology for Ruby (and if I am please correct me), but Google just isn't helping me on this one.

What I have is a class (call it OrderController) that extends another class (call it BaseStoreController). In the BaseStoreController I have defined a `before_filter` that is used throughout my site, with the small except of my OrderController. In this very particular situation I needed to define a custom `before_filter` that needs to do some additional logic and then call the `before_filter` defined in my BaseStoreController.

What I do not know is how to do this.

Here is what I've tried, but it appears that the 'super' keyword isn't what I was expecting it to be:

```
class BaseStoreController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :authorize

    protected
        def authorize
            #common authroization logic here
        end
 end
```

and

```
class OrderController < BaseStoreController
    before_filter :authorize

    protected
        def authorize
            #additional authroization logic here
            super.authorize
        end
 end
```

The end result of my code is that the authorize method in the OrderController is failing with the following error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.authorize
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Have you tried calling the base class's "`authorize`" method with just "`super`" instead of "`super.authorize`"?

Comment: wow!

I guess my experience with other languages was harming me on this one... I expected super to be a reference to the base class... not a reference to the base class method I was hiding.

That worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: In Ruby, `super` is a call to the inherited version of the method, so you were calling `authorize` on whatever that returned -- in this case, `nil`.

Comment: How would one actually reference the base class?