# strange output on calling base class method from extended module

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

What I want to achieve is something like below, i.e. calling a base class method from extended modules method:

```
class BaseClass
  def behavior
    puts 'base class behavior'
  end
end

module ChildModule
  def behavior
   super.behavior
   puts 'child module behavior'
  end
end

o = BaseClass.new
o.extend ChildModule
o.behavior
```

and it outputs as follows (with ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux])

```
base class behavior
t.rb:9:in `behavior': undefined method `behavior' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
       from t.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

My guess is that I can not use `super`, as `super` does not exist in the module. But it prints out that line from the `super` method, is that strange?

How do I achieve it what I want above?

Answer by @davidrac is working, however being more curious, would like to know, how can I get a handle to base class instance? Say for instance I added the following method to BaseClass

```
def behavior2
  puts 'base class behavior2'
end
```

and overrides it in ChildModule. Now from ChildModule behavior can I make a call to behavior2 of BaseModule?

Comment: Possible duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547074/calling-base-class-method-from-overloaded-method-in-sub-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
module ChildModule
  def behavior
   super
   puts 'child module behavior'
  end
end
```

Comment: just being curious, modifying my question to know how I get handle to base class

Comment: simply use MyClass.superclass. see here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html

Comment: but MyClass is not a class but a module here

Comment: Oh, now I see. A module may not inherit from anything. I don't see in your code any indication that BaseClass is the superclass of ChildModule